# Swami Vivekananda wearing turban?

Tags: vivekananda

In many pictures of Swami Vivekananda, it is seen that he is wearing a saffron turban.As per wiki article on [Swami ji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swami_Vivekananda), it is said he was a Hindu monk. My question is, was it a Hindu monk culture to wear turban or was it his personal life style that he adopted?

For reference, Here is a picture from same article taken in Chicago:

[image]

Comment: it was donned on him as a mark of respect when he left for Chicago. I believe something to this effect is mentioned in his Complete Works, @SwamiVishwananda might be able to throw light

Comment: @ram I see. Let's wait for the answer then. Or else if you know post that.

Comment: many sadhus carry a cloth with them (as do many Indians) that they can use for different purposes, including putting on their head.

Comment: @Swami So there is no specific significance of wearing a turban by a Hindu monk. Is it?

Comment: They have to cover thier head.  Whether is turban or otherwise

Comment: @Rakesh Covering head? Why?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto as per sankara sanyasa rules

Comment: @Rakesh But same way other Sanyasis never seen to cover their head.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto maybe because others dont do tonsure